# JavaScript convert date format to "YYYY-MM-DD"

Tags: javascript, javascript-date

I have a JavaScript string date:

js code:

```
const lastDayDate = new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
const options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
const formattedDate = lastDayDate.toLocaleDateString('se-SE', options);
```

The output of console.log(formattedDate) is something like:

```
05/31/2023
```

My question is how to convert it to :

```
2023-05-31
```

Any friend can help ?

Comment: You don't want locale format. Maybe `lastDayDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this?

```
lastDayDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76056658/javascript-const-txt-change-to-new-line-not-work

Comment: It got closed for already having answers. Just use:

    const obj = {"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York\n", "home":"yes"}

No need for JSON.parse and newline is "\n" not forward slash.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, `lastDayDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]` will return UTC Date instead of Local Date. So the correct way to handle this is with `formatDate` function which gets a local date as year, month, and day.

```js
let formatDate = (date) => {
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  const localDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
  return localDate;
};

const lastDayDate = new Date(2023, 4 + 1, 0);
console.log(lastDayDate);
const formattedDate = formatDate(lastDayDate);
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76056658/javascript-const-txt-change-to-new-line-not-work

Comment: Hi friend can you help with this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76094451/javascript-convert-api-to-object-and-create-another-value-to-hold-its-value

Answer (score 1):

one way: `const formattedDate = lastDayDate.toJSON().slice(0, 10);`

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76056658/javascript-const-txt-change-to-new-line-not-work