# Convert API to object and create another value to hold its value

Tags: javascript

I can use the following function to convert an API to an object and print it out:

```
function covertApiTobj(){
    fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=dev')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));}
```

But how can I create another variable to let it equal to the object that has been converted from the API, something like this:

```
function covertApiTobj(){
    fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=dev')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
    
    const newdata = fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=dev')
      .then(res => res.json())
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You can't do that. It's an asynchronous operation, so you are stuck with doing the work you want to do in your `.then()` callback. You can use `async` and `await` to make things *seem* like synchronous programming, but it still is not synchronous.

Comment: You wanna fetch two API results, deserialize the returned JSON to JS objects and then compare them? It is very much unclear what you're asking for, I'm afraid.

Comment: You're not "converting" the API, you're making a request to it. If you want the value from the response body, read https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3001761.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create `Promise` to pass a fetch response on a new variable and `await` the result in `async` function like this:

```js
let getData = async() => {
  return fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=dev')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => res)
  .catch(err => err);
}
(async () => {
  let data = await getData();
  let newdata = await getData();
  console.log('data:',data);
  console.log('newdata:',newdata);
})();
```

Comment: `fetch()` already returns a Promise; there's no need to create a new one

Comment: this is the [explicit promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/633183)

Comment: @Pointy Omg, Thanks. I have realized my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise chaining.
Here is an example:

```
let apiUrl = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=dev';
let jsonData;

fetch(apiUrl)
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    jsonData = data;
    console.log('JSON data saved:', jsonData);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  });
```